# Kotlin performance of Interface vs Function Invocation

Tags: java, android, interface, kotlin, function-calls

In Kotlin, as we can use functions as variables, i tend to replace interfaces with function calls like this:

```
class A {

    private var listener: AA? = null
    var callThis: (() -> Unit) ? = null)

    fun somethingHere() {
        callThis?.invoke()
        listener?.callThis2()
    }

    fun attachListener(listener: AA) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    interface AA {
        fun callThis2()
    }
}

class B {
    init {
        val objectA = A()
        objectA.callThis = {}
        objectA.attachListener(object : A.AA {
            override fun callThis2() {
            }
        })

    }
}
```

As I'm pretty new to Kotlin, i would like to know the differences and in what scenarios should i use function calls vs interfaces, except for the (obviously) abstraction. Or is it the same, and the function call does exactly the same as anonymous inner classes

The function is called many times, each 100s precisely, and i would like to know, in terms of performance, which on is better

Comment: Could you please reformat the code? In it's current state it is kinda hard to read. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lambda in Kotlin is compiled to an anonymous inner class. Therefore, the performance of the two scenarios will be exactly the same.